# Adding new command to module through C-API?

Tags: python, python-c-api

How would I dynamically add methods to my module through the C-API?  I have many functions I need to register, and they are not in the same array. I assume I can initialize the module with a NULL method table, as the documentation says that's possible.

```
PyObject *mymod = Py_InitModule("my", NULL);
```

What is the name of a function to add my methods one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you'll have to get ahold of the module dict first:

```
d = PyModule_GetDict(m);
```

Store the module name in a PyString object:

```
n = PyString_FromString("modname");
```

Then properly populate a [PyMethodDef](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html?highlight=pymethoddef#PyMethodDef) struct `ml` and create a new callable:

```
v = PyCFunction_NewEx(&ml, (PyObject*)NULL, n);
```

and add this callable keyed by the function name to the module dict:

```
PyDict_SetItemString(d, ml->ml_name, v);
```

I've obviously skipped all relevant error checks.

All this is my interpretation about what [`Py_InitModule4`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/08400969067e/Python/modsupport.c) does (`Py_InitModule` is a macro calling `Py_InitModule4` with default arguments).